# gem 'dm-core' not found

Tags: ruby, apache, sinatra, passenger, datamapper

I'm trying to use DataMapper in my Ruby/Sinatra application. When Passenger restarted the server, however, I got a lovely error page telling me that I got a LoadError when trying to `require 'dm-core'`.

Weird. Here's my list of installed gems:

```
max indexer $ gem list | grep dm
dm-aggregates (1.2.0)
dm-constraints (1.2.0)
dm-core (1.2.0)
dm-migrations (1.2.0)
dm-redis-adapter (0.7.0)
dm-serializer (1.2.2)
dm-timestamps (1.2.0)
dm-transactions (1.2.0)
dm-types (1.2.2)
dm-validations (1.2.0)
max indexer $ gem list | grep mapper
data_mapper (1.2.0)
```

I clearly have `dm-*` and `data_mapper`, so what's going on?

Comment: Are you using Bundler? If so, perhaps you just need to add the gems to your Gemfile.

Comment: No, I'm not; just requiring it straight out of the file. Maybe I should make a Gemfile though.

Comment: The other thing that comes to mind is to check that Passenger is using the same installation of Ruby as the one where the dm- gems are installed (not sure how to do that – you’d need to check the docs).

Comment: I'm using rvm, and that changes the system ruby, so it's most likely the same :-/